# MySQL PHP - Returned column and split it into 2 arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP and MySQL to pull some rows from a table. One column is called "item_notes" and this column has a dynamic number of comma-delimited values in it. If I printed 1 row, the column would look something like this:

```
item_1, new_item_1, ** note_1, ** note_2, item_2, ** note_3, old_item_1, new_item2
```

Is there a way I can split this into 2 arrays using PHP, where 1 array is has only values that start with a ** and the ones that don't go into the other array?

Comment: Yes of course there is a way. Its called a F.L.O.C

Comment: Start by looking at `explode()` [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 1):

As you show no effort trying, I suppose I'll just leave it here)))

```
$s = 'item_1, new_item_1, ** note_1, ** note_2, item_2, ** note_3, old_item_1, new_item2';
$items = array_map('trim', explode(',', $s));
$notes = $starredNotes = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (0 === strpos($item, '**')) {
        $starredNotes[] = $item;
    } else {
        $notes[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is what a F.L.O.C looks like :)